# What is the best practice to input a bunch of data in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What is the best practice to upload bunch of data(multiple rows) at once time. I don't want to upload any files on the server.
Is it good to have a text area to input data with a predefined structure(format). And create a small parser to read and analyze that input to insert it into to the database.

**Edit:**
I have the data set in `excel` file. I want to store it in the database, I don't want to upload the server.

**Data sample :**

```
      id             fid              sid               name
      --------------------------------------------------------------
  1-  3a3458         2a2125           3a4541            John Smith
  2-  313547         3a4541           212145            Albert koku
      .....................
      ............... 
      .........
100-  ...
```

Comment: Where will the data be coming from?

Comment: Please give us an idea what kind of data you are talking about. Why do you want to upload it in one step? And why not just use a normal html form with multiple text fields?

Comment: Where do the data come from? Should them be inserted by a user? Is data validation required?

Answer (score 0):

Since the data has already a predefined structure, to avoid manual errors and parsing I would build an interface which contains a `<table>` and the user will fill the corresponding data and then submit it to the server.

But if you don't want to bother to guide the user and help him then you could of course use a `<textarea>` in which the user could enter the data under some known form: CSV, JSON, XML, ... and then do the parsing on the server.